# How do I check if the line is over?

Tags: c, string, file, line, scanf

I ran into a problem today. I can't find a way to check if a line in a file is over and the words are read from the next one already. I read word by word from the file using fscanf, then process the word as I need to and print it out into another file but there is a problem.

for example my data file is:

```
Hello, how are you
doing?
```

and the result file shows:

```
Hello, how are you doing?
```

but i need the words to be in the same lines from which I took them. Please keep in mind that I need those words one by one, that is why I don't use `getline()`

here is my code of how I read words from the file:

```
while( fscanf(file, "%s", A) != EOF )
        {
            check(A, B, &a); // I edit the words and put them in B string
                             // which is printed to the write file
        }
```

Thank you for any tips!

Comment: Use `getline`, then do whatever you want with the lines -- get the words out of them one by one if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the line into a string with `getline()` or `fgets()`, then use `sscanf` to get the words out of this string.

Comment: Thank you for the input, it seems like this is the way to go :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple logic instead, like matching strings like `.` or `?` which generally ends lines.

Comment: I doubt that would work since the kind of text that could be stored in the file is completely random with no possible prediction but thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for end of line by adding check. 
As the end-of-line is represented by the newline character, which is '\n'. so in while loop instead of copying entire thing do it line by line with the help of check for '\n'

Comment: I have tried that, however it did not do the trick (most likely because i read the file word by word instead of the whole line) and completely crashed the program. Thank you for the input!